# How to fix Time Capsule slowdown on file dialogs?

Tags: finder, macos, time-machine, time-capsule

I've got a fairly recent model Time Capsule running backup for my Macbook Pro (Late 2013). Ever since upgrading to Yosemite I've noticed an occasional slow down when bringing up a file open or save dialog in most applications.

The delay is more than 5 seconds, and it only happens if a file dialog hasn't been displayed in a while. I can keep Finder windows open, and that doesn't seem to affect it.

The only pattern I've noticed is that I usually hear the Time Capsule drive spin up. Since I see the Time Capsule in the file dialog it seems like that is a likely candidate. It is rather annoying and would love to do something about it.

Time Capsule is only used for Time Machine purposes. I don't store or access any other files on it. It does not have any additional USB drives attached to it. My Macbook has a wired connection to the Time Capsule.

Comment: if it's being used for time machine only, i'm not sure why the machine is trying to wake it and present it as a place to save/open a file from.  have you never mounted it as a share directly?  there may be an option to make it not present itself as a share on the network (but hopefully will still work for TM)